# Create a textfield which can include html markup

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I was wondering how one could create something that resembles a textfield, but can contain html elements in it.  For example, something like what Stackoverflow uses for tags on its "Ask Question" page.  Can this be done this done using a particular plugin/library or does it need to be created from scratch?

I have seen some solutions using the "contenteditable" property, but I am worried about cross browser compatibility. In fact it would appear that the Stackoverflow example does not use this.  I have tried searching for info on how to do this but haven't found anything.  Would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create it from scratch. Here is the one I use: [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php)

Answer (score 0):

You might also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950018/how-do-online-rich-text-editors-work#answer-1950040) useful. But you dont need to make a new one. There are a plenty of open source options available.